# SELECT query with results from other SELECT query in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT foo, bar FROM my_table WHERE foo = "aaa" OR bar = "yyy" LIMIT 1;
```

Let's assume the result of this query is:

| foo | bar |
| --- | --- |
| xxx | yyy |

Since I used `LIMIT 1` there will be **only one** returning row.

Now I want to make a new SQL query with the results in WHERE clause, like this:

```
SELECT foo, bar FROM my_table WHERE foo = "xxx" OR bar = "yyy" LIMIT 1;
```

`foo = "xxx"` AND `bar = "yyy"` are the results of the first query.

Of course, I could grab the results from the first query and copy/paste them into the WHERE clause of the second query (manually or programmatically e.g. with PHP) but this isn't really convenient.

How can I combine these two queries into one?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `IN` clause with two parameters

```
SELECT 
    foo, bar
FROM
    my_table
WHERE
    (foo , bar) IN (SELECT 
            foo, bar
        FROM
            my_table
        WHERE
            foo = 'aaa' OR bar = 'yyy'
        LIMIT 1)
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first query as a subquery on an inner join clause.

Try:

```
SELECT mt1.foo, 
       mt1.bar 
FROM my_table  mt1 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT foo, 
                    bar 
             FROM my_table 
             WHERE foo = "aaa" 
             OR bar = "yyy" 
             LIMIT 1
            ) as mt2 on mt1.foo=mt2.foo or mt1.bar=mt2.bar 
LIMIT 1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support prepared statements with an arbitrary number of comparisons, you could use a comma-delimited argument to `FIND_IN_SET`:

```sql
SELECT foo, bar
FROM my_table
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(foo, 'aaa,xxx') > 0     --prepared arg 1
    OR bar = 'yyy'                        --prepared arg 2
LIMIT 1;
```

This would allow you to send the arguments as: `'aaa,xxx', 'yyy'`, just 2 strings.

Comment: Thanks! But this doesn't help me. I cannot write `xxx` into the query, because I don't know this yet. This is the value I get from the first query. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: I think the simplest solution in that case would be to make use of the application logic on your php end, using the 1-line query repeatedly (as a prepared statement). If you want to combine them, you'll end up with nested subqueries like in @nbk's answer (and it will only get more convoluted as you need more than 2 queries).